# When i fill in 3 form inputs my end result does not display. But when i fill in 2 of the 3 inputs the results gets displayed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I have a function that makes use of 3 inputs. Unfortunately when i fill in all 3 the inputs. The result shows up for 1 second and goes away... But when i fill in only 2 of the 3 inputs. The result will show up, but of course is missing some of the input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
      <h1> BMI Calculator</h1>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Lengte</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_lengte" required><span>cm</span><br>
    <label><b>Gewicht</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_gewicht" required><span>kg</span><br>
    <label><b>Leeftijd</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_leeftijd" required><span>jr</span><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="showBMI();" value="Calculate">Berekenen</button><br/>
    <label>&nbsp;</label><br>
    <label>Your BMI: </label>
        <p><span id='display'></span></p>
 </form>

</body>
</html>

    function showBMI() {

        var gewicht = document.getElementById("user_gewicht").value;
        var lengte = document.getElementById("user_lengte").value;
        var leeftijd = document.getElementById("user_leeftijd").value;


        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
        (88.362 + (13.397 * gewicht) + (4.799 * lengte) - (5.677 * leeftijd)).toFixed(2)

        //88.362 + ( 13.397 x weight in kg ) + ( 4.799 x height in cm ) - ( 5.677 x age in years )
};
```

I would like to be able to fill in all 3 the inputs and have it displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a button type as submit, the default behaviour of it is to submit the form and force refresh of the page, which you can disable by passing the event to `showBMI` method and using `event.preventDefault();`

```js
function showBMI(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        

        var gewicht = document.getElementById("user_gewicht").value;
        var lengte = document.getElementById("user_lengte").value;
        var leeftijd = document.getElementById("user_leeftijd").value;


        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
        (88.362 + (13.397 * gewicht) + (4.799 * lengte) - (5.677 * leeftijd)).toFixed(2)

        //88.362 + ( 13.397 x weight in kg ) + ( 4.799 x height in cm ) - ( 5.677 x age in years )
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
      <h1> BMI Calculator</h1>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Lengte</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_lengte" required><span>cm</span><br>
    <label><b>Gewicht</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_gewicht" required><span>kg</span><br>
    <label><b>Leeftijd</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_leeftijd" required><span>jr</span><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="showBMI(event);" value="Calculate">Berekenen</button><br/>
    <label>&nbsp;</label><br>
    <label>Your BMI: </label>
        <p><span id='display'></span></p>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I had just found a work around, but this is much better!

Answer (score 0):

Change button type to "button"

```
<button type="button" onclick="showBMI();" value="Calculate">Berekenen</button><br/>
```

Comment: Would you be so nice to explain the difference? What would type="button" do instead of "submit"?

Comment: When you click type="submit" it will trigger form submit, to prevent this you can use type="button".

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showBMI() {

        var gewicht = document.getElementById("user_gewicht").value;
        var lengte = document.getElementById("user_lengte").value;
        var leeftijd = document.getElementById("user_leeftijd").value;


        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
        (88.362 + (13.397 * gewicht) + (4.799 * lengte) - (5.677 * leeftijd)).toFixed(2)

        //88.362 + ( 13.397 x weight in kg ) + ( 4.799 x height in cm ) - ( 5.677 x age in years )
};


$(document).on('click', '#showBMI', function (e) {

showBMI();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
      <h1> BMI Calculator</h1>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Lengte</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_lengte" required><span>cm</span><br>
    <label><b>Gewicht</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_gewicht" required><span>kg</span><br>
    <label><b>Leeftijd</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_leeftijd" required><span>jr</span><br>
<button id="showBMI" value="Calculate">Berekenen</button><br/>
    <label>&nbsp;</label><br>
    <label>Your BMI: </label>
        <p><span id='display'></span></p>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
function showBMI() {

        var gewicht = document.getElementById("user_gewicht").value;
        var lengte = document.getElementById("user_lengte").value;
        var leeftijd = document.getElementById("user_leeftijd").value;


        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
        (88.362 + (13.397 * gewicht) + (4.799 * lengte) - (5.677 * leeftijd)).toFixed(2)

        //88.362 + ( 13.397 x weight in kg ) + ( 4.799 x height in cm ) - ( 5.677 x age in years )
};


$(document).on('click', '#showBMI', function (e) {

showBMI();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
      <h1> BMI Calculator</h1>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Lengte</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_lengte" required><span>cm</span><br>
    <label><b>Gewicht</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_gewicht" required><span>kg</span><br>
    <label><b>Leeftijd</b></label>
        <input type="number" name="message" id="user_leeftijd" required><span>jr</span><br>
<button id="showBMI" value="Calculate">Berekenen</button><br/>
    <label>&nbsp;</label><br>
    <label>Your BMI: </label>
        <p><span id='display'></span></p>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what it changes? I see some changes but i don't know what the side effects are?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add onsubmit event to the form tag

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

Then it will be good to remove onclick event from submit button and call showBMI() method to onsubmit event like this:

```
<form onsubmit="showBMI(); return false">
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out!